# Azure Websites Git Deployment dropping "/" in SCM_BUILD_ARGS

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

### Description

We are in a current project based on MVC4/Umbraco using Azure Websites to host it.

We are using SCM_BUILD_ARGS to change between different build setups depending on which site in Azure we deploy to (Test and Prod).

This is done by defining an app setting in the UI:

> SCM_BUILD_ARGS = /p:Environment=Test

Earlier we used Bitbucket Integration to deploy and here this setting worked like a champ.

We have now switched to using Git Deployment, pushing the changes from our build server when tests have passed. 
But when we do this, we get a lovely error.

> "MSB1008: Only one project can be specified."

Trying to redeploy the same failed deployment from the UI on Azure works though.

After some trial and error I ended going into the deploy.cmd and outputting the `%SCM_BUILD_ARGS%` value in the script.
It looks like the `/` gets dropped from SCM_BUILD_ARGS but only when using Git deploy, not Bitbucket Integration or redeploy from UI.

### Workaround

As workaround I have for now added a `/` to the deploy.cmd script in front of the `%SCM_BUILD_ARGS%`, but this of course breaks redeploy, since we then have `//p:Environment=Test` in the MSBuild command when the value of `%SCM_BUILD_ARGS%` has been inserted.

```
:: 2. Build to the temporary path
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
:: Added / to SCM_BUILD_ARGS
  %MSBUILD_PATH% "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\www\www.csproj" [....]  /%SCM_BUILD_ARGS%
) ELSE (
  %MSBUILD_PATH% "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\www\www.csproj" [....] /%SCM_BUILD_ARGS%
)
```

### Question

Anyone know of a better solution for this problem or is it possibly a bug in Kudu?
We would love to have both deploy from Git and Redeploy working.

Comment: Strange, we'll need to debug this. For things like that that look like Kudu bugs, it's probably best to open an issue directly on https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu, so you can track the resolution there.

Comment: Hopefully I won't be stumbling over more bugs, but I will definitely open an issue if it happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could you try changing from "/" to "-"?   For instance, AppSettings from `/p:Environment=Test` to `-p:Environment=Test`, see if it helps.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

`-p:Environment=Test` did not work for me, the setting which worked for me at the time of this writing (September 2015) was 
    `-p:Configuration=Test`

Answer (score 0):

There is clearly a Kudu bug in there, and you should open an issue on https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu. But for now, I can give you a workaround.

Instead of using an App Setting, include a .deployment file at the root of your repo, containing:

```
[config]
SCM_BUILD_ARGS = /p:Environment=Test
```

I think this will work in all cases. I suspect the bug has to do with bash messing up the environment in post receive hook scenarios, which only apply to direct git push but not to Bitbucket and Redeploy scenarios.

UPDATE: In fact, it's easy to see such weird bash behavior. Try this:

- Open cmd.exe
- Run: `set foo=/abc` to set a variable
- Run `bash`
- From bash, run `cmd` to launch a new cmd on top of bash (so cmd -> bash -> cmd)
- Run `set foo` to get the value of foo

Result:

```
FOO=C:/Program Files (x86)/git/abc
```

So the value gets completely messed up. The key also gets upper cases, though that's mostly harmless. Strange stuff...

Comment: Use Suwat's answer instead, which is a lot simpler. It was probably a known issue after all, and may not be easily fixable in Kudu, but it's simple enough to use a dash instead of a slash :)